# django save error

Tags: python, django, save

```
for *** :
   try:
       xx = A(
          a=x,
          b=y
       )
       xx.save()
   except:
     pass
```

here is my question: once one of the "xx" saved error, others will not save success.
Does any one know why? thanks!

here is the error message

```
Exception
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] RuntimeError
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] :
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] 'generator ignored GeneratorExit'
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] in
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,880: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] <generator object msg_iter_page at 0x2ec28c0>
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,880: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] ignored
```

Comment: please show us error msg by removing `try: except:` block,

Comment: Exception
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] RuntimeError
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] :
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] 'generator ignored GeneratorExit'
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,879: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] in
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,880: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] <generator object msg_iter_page at 0x2ec28c0>
[2011-08-22 14:02:23,880: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You catch every exception with this statement:

```
except:
   pass
```

GeneratorExit is just an exception. This should not be caught. Please catch only the exceptions, you expect.

Comment: thanks, I'm a beginner, how to cache the exception that I want.

Comment: You should **catch** them, not **cache**. Just like this:
`except IOError, exc:`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't catch `GeneratorExit`. If you want to catch all exceptions inherited from `Exception` rather then from `BaseException` you should change your code for:

```
for *** :
   try:
       xx = A(
          a=x,
          b=y
       )
       xx.save()
   except Exception:
     pass
```