# Django ORM unique_together not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working with django 1.6 and postgressql. I'm trying to set up a composite unique key made up of name and addresses fields. My Model:

```
class MU2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="",unique=True)
    addresses = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    ......

class Meta:
   unique_together = ("name", "addresses")
```

in My view:

```
for practice in practices:
    p =MU2(**practice)
    try:
        p.save()
    except ValidationError:
       pass
```

The composite key is not working and I am getting duplicated records on both name and addresses fields.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you swallowing the ValidationError? What's the point of doing that?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't know what 'swallowing' means in this context. I'm trying to follow the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960339/basic-handling-of-unique-column-integrityerror-with-django-orm. I was not able to find a reference in the django docs to what error , is produced when a unique_together constraint is violated, but another stackoverflow post seemed to indicate ValidationError

Comment: You're catching the exception, and then ignoring it. That is almost always a very bad thing to do. Exceptions are raised for a reason, and you should actually handle it, or let it bubble up and be reported. What you should never do is just do "pass".

Comment: Understood, thanks. So how should I handle a situation as in the above post where I want the ORM to simply not insert the new record and move onto the next record without indicating a problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960339/basic-handling-of-unique-column-integrityerror-with-django-orm

Comment: At the very least log the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three things you are "doing wrong":

1. your `class Meta` statement is badly indented - it should be at the same level as the fields declarations
2. `unique_together` expects a tuple of tuples, not a single tuple
3. your 'pass' except clause prevents you from getting any useful debugging information if something goes wrong. Not that it would solve your current problem but it's still wrong...

Also, an address is not a 2600 characters long "kitchen sink" bit bucket (it's usually a structured datatype with two or thre address lines, a zip code, a city name etc - in a relational model it could / should be a table on it's own), and few SQL databases will deal with 2600 characters long `varchar` field anyway, and let's not talk about using it as part of a composite index...

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I deleted the table and made the 2 fixes you suggested in my code and resynced to recreate the table, (please see above) , however the behavior is unchanged.

Comment: Your code is still badly indented so `Meta` doesn't belong to your model class. Also unique_together should be a tuple of tuples not a single tuple.

Comment: Thanks again Bruno, I didn't understand that the meta class is WITHIN the model class. numerous stackoverflow examples don't show it that way, but as a separate class .Also I did not find a reference in the django docs to proper indentation. I have fixed the indentation in my code and it is now working correctly!